# Access Variables of ViewController Before Popping To It

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a home button which triggers this code when pressed. 
I need to change a variable within the viewController I am popping to **before** I pop to it. Is there any way to do this?

```
func goHome(){

        let switchViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1] as! UIViewController
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(switchViewController, animated: true)

    }
```

This is how I thought you would go about it but no variables of the viewController appear in the autocomplete window.

```
switchViewController.x = 5
```

Any information on how to go about this and/or why this isn't working as is would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `switchViewController` as a generic `UIViewController`, which has no variable `.x`.

You should set it as the correct class, which in this case would be whatever you named the class that has the 'x' variable:

```
let switchViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1] as! SwitchViewController
switchViewController.x = 5
```

In this case I've used the class name `SwitchViewController`, which means you'd need a .Swift class file like so:

```
import UIKit

class SwitchViewController: UIViewController {

    var x: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, duhh. Thanks a lot. I have only been using Swift for the last 2 months so sometimes I skip obvious stuff. I appreciate the help Hal.

Answer (score 0):

What type of `UIViewController` your `switchViewController` is?
In order to have custom variables in the the `UIViewController`, you would need to subclass it, and when getting it back, you would do it like this:

```
func goHome(){

    let switchViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1] as! YourViewController
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(switchViewController, animated: true)

}
```

Taking `x` as the example variable, `UIViewController` has no variable of this type, but your subclass (which i expect you have one) of `UIViewController` might have, and then auto-complete would kick in.

Comment: The first few times I read your response I wasn't sure what you meant by subclassing. Though after I read Hal's response and figured out what I was doing wrong I came back and reread yours to realize you also had posted the answer as well. You're 100% right when you say UIViewController doesn't have a variable called 'x', but my speciesViewController class does. Thanks for the help Erakk :) .